# How can I retrieve data using a model and pass it to be used in a controller using CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, session, codeigniter, model, controller

From a user login form i need to use their `username ($this->input->post('username'))` to query against the `membership` table in my database so that I can retrieve the users `firstname` and `lastname`, which I believe should be done via a model called from my controller. I then need to pass that data back to my controller to use the `firstname` and `lastname` to add in to my session `userdata` which is set in my controller, as shown below.

```
$data = array(
   'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
   'firstname' => //need to retrieve value from database,
   'lastname' => //need to retrieve value from database,
   'is_logged_in' => true
);

$this->session->set_userdata($data);
```

Thanks,
Kristan.

Comment: did you read the documentation ? one of the best things about CI: documentations is realy realy good .

Answer (score 2):

In your model, make a function to retrieve the first and last name of a user:

```
 public function get_user_details($username){
     // retrieve contents from db:
     // the first username here is the name of the column in your table

     $query = $this->db->select('firstname, lastname')
                       ->where('username', $username)
                       ->get('membership');
     return $query->result_array();
 }
```

In your controller, like you were doijng, grab the POST contents in your controller:

```
 $username = $this->input->post('username');
```

Then, from your controller, call your model function but save the output of that model function in a variable:

```
 $data = $this->user_model->get_user_details($username);
```

After that, you can do what you were trying to do:

```
 $this->session->set_userdata($data);
```

Hope that helps. I wrote this from the top of my head but it should work. I also suggest you read the CI documentation through because it really is some of the best documentation I have ever seen for a framework. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Please check [CodeIgniter user guide for model](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html). The example of `Blog` controller and `Blog` model will answer you.

```
class Blogmodel extends CI_Model {

    var $title   = '';
    var $content = '';
    var $date    = '';

    function __construct()
    {
        // Call the Model constructor
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function get_last_ten_entries()
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('entries', 10);
        return $query->result();
    }

    function insert_entry()
    {
        $this->title   = $_POST['title']; // please read the below note
        $this->content = $_POST['content'];
        $this->date    = time();

        $this->db->insert('entries', $this);
    }

    function update_entry()
    {
        $this->title   = $_POST['title'];
        $this->content = $_POST['content'];
        $this->date    = time();

        $this->db->update('entries', $this, array('id' => $_POST['id']));
    }

}

class Blog_controller extends CI_Controller {

    function blog()
    {
        $this->load->model('Blog');

        $data['query'] = $this->Blog->get_last_ten_entries();

        $this->load->view('blog', $data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to create a model.

```
class Membership_model extends CI_Model {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function getUser($username) {
        $query = $this->db->get_where('membership', array('username' => $username));
        return $query->result_array();
    }
}
```

then in your controller, use the membership model to retrieve data. Calling this function: `$this->membership_model->getUser($this->input->post('username'));`